# Javascript indexOf method

Tags: javascript

I recently came across this little problem to solve on a website, counting the number of vowels in a string. I succeeded using a switch statement, but when I looked at the authors solution they had used the following function.

```
function vowel_count(str1) {
var vowel_list = 'aeiouAEIOU';
var vcount = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < str1.length ; x++) {
    if (vowel_list.indexOf(str1[x]) !== -1) {
        vcount += 1;
    }

}
return vcount;
}
alert(vowel_count("The quick brown fox"));
```

Can anyone please explain what exactly is happening in the if statement,
I can see the index of whatever string that is passed to the function is being used but why would the statement == or !== -1. I'm a bit confused as to how the function is checking the string.
      Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Although personally I'd do it like this: `function vowel_count(str) {return str.match(/aeiou/ig).length;}` - much simpler.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so would I, but beware that `.length` will fail if there's no vowels, since `.match` returns `null`

Comment: @Alnitak Oh whoops, so it does. Okay, so `return (str.match(/aeiou/ig)||[]).length;` then!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that works ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexOf() function returns the index of an element we're looking for in a given array. However, if the element is nowhere to be found in the array, indexOf() returns -1 instead.
So in your case:

```
if (vowel_list.indexOf(str1[x]) !== -1) {
```

means something like "if the current letter can be found in my list of vowels".
Does that make sense ?

Comment: Perfect thank you. so it will always return - 1 if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. It returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, like most programming languages, starts counting from `0`.

`"foo".indexOf('f');` is `0`.

The function returns `-1` if the value isn't found.